# Your Ruby version is 2.2.4, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.1

Tags: ruby

How can I update my ruby version to from 2.2.4 to 2.3.1
I am new to Ruby, I am using windows 8 and I do not have any ruby version manager install.

**I can not change the ruby version on the gem file because I have to use the ruby version everybody else is using. So changin the ruby version on the gem file is not a solution**

**I can not use a ruby version manager.**

Comment: If you cannot use a version manager and you are working with Ruby... then you have a problem, my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org) to install version 2.3.1.

Comment: I wish I could do that but there is no ruby installer for version 2.3.1 at http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: Michael wrote *Ruby*Installer not *Rails*Installer. And there are multiple 2.3.1 Versions of Ruby on [RubyInstaller for Windows' download page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)!